# Saving inverse owner of @ManyToMany relationship in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, save

I use many-to-many relationship between User and Answer. Answer is owner :

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_answer", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "answer_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
```

User is inverse owner :

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Answer.class)
    public Set<Answer> getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }
```

The code to save owner Answer and have join table user_answer with new records is ok!
This is code to save inverse owner

```
User user=createUser();
//answer with id 6 is already in db
Answer answer = new Answer(6);
answer.getUsers().add(user);
user.getAnswers().add(answer);
currentSession().save(user);
```

It is not working saving for me only user without saving corresponding rows into user_answer. Primary key of User entity is autogenerated by db when saving.

What are the reasons that join table is not populated with new rows when saving inverse owner User?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is clearly pointed in hibernate reference [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-bidirectional)

That is I need to save inverse owner at first and then owner :

```
currentSession().save(inverseOwner);
currentSession().save(owner);
```

Then join table will be populated with corresponding values